# Extending loopback models using the same collection in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

Is it possible to use the loopback-connector-mongodb and have extended loopback models use the same collection in mongodb? I'm essentially looking for the same feature as [mongoose's model discriminator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.7.x/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible, however I would reccomend you to do some extensive testing to pinpoint unexpected behaviors with, for example, model relations.

Let's say you had a Women model

```
{
  "name":"Woman",
  "plural:"Women",
  "options":{
    "mongodb":{
      "collection":"woman"
    },
  },
  "properties":{
    "id":{...},
    "name":{...},
    "status":{...},
    "age":{...}
  }
}
```

now, you could define a singleWomen model

```
{
  "name":"singleWoman", 
  "plural":"singleWomen",
  "base":"Woman",
  "scopes":{
    "where":{
      "status":"single"
    }
  }
};
```

I'm not sure that inserting a new record on singleWoman would enforce the status field to equal "single". I'm pretty sure it won't, so you'll have to add some business logic to patch that behavior.